# Bootstrap 3 buttons - not flat?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new to Bootstrap and I have some issues working out some of the items.

I like the way the "built-in" buttons from Bootstrap look like (i.e.: flat) but even when I download the latest version of Bootstrap I get buttons with gradients.

Why is that ?

Comment: It's the theme changing, you should be able to remove the theme CSS that's been added in and revert back to defaults.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`bootstrap-theme.css` makes Bootstrap have gradients - Remove it. This won't break anything.

Comment: Right I have a link to bootstrap-theme.css. Whe  I remove it it does solve the issue. But what will I lose other than gradients if I don't use the theme ?

Comment: Pretty much nothing other then the gradients.

Comment: The theme unflattens things. I think that's what you want.

Comment: Nice, thx for the answer, couldn't find that info anywhere :P

Comment: Incase you are looking for more themes, I recently found this site (I don't own it, or take responsibility for anything on it) https://bootswatch.com

Comment: If somebody had it, you also have to remove `bootstrap-theme.min.css`